# iCloud Drive Saving Document Edits to Archive

Tags: icloud, finder, network, ms-office, software

I have an iCloud drive folder where I store my word documents. I edit the word documents while they are located in iCloud Drive. I recently noticed when I opened up a word document that it was the version of the document from 3 days ago, even though I had made edits today on the same computer and closed out the document. There was no cloud image next to the document suggesting it had yet to upload.

To my great relief, I found the edited version of my document (reflecting all the work I had done within the last few hours) in the iCloud Drive Archive folder.

Why in the world does the actual iCloud Drive folder not have the newest version, why is the newest version in the archive folder, and how can I avoid this nightmare in the future?